# so, the debug version of my code works, but the release doesn't

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, malloc, release

like the title says, the debug version of my code works, but the release, doesnt, it just exits the program without doing nothing, if i put it in release mode and use debug, i get an exception thrown Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6DA208CB0 in codec.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.
and a big screen saying Symbol file not loaded, in my program i use malloc, because i needed an array of variable size, could that be the problem ?, in debug mode i have a warning named dereferencing null pointer, at the pointer i used malloc on
//here's some `code`

```
        for (int j = 0; j < animation->servoTableSize.cols; j++)
    {
        // Analyze pixel change
        uint8_t* LocalMaximums = (uint8_t*)malloc((animation->servoFrameCount) * sizeof(uint8_t));
        //^^^ remembers the frames in which local maximums are
        int NumberOfSpikes = 0;
        //^^^remembers how many spikes there are


        //here we search for local spikes (local maximums)
        for (int FrameNumber = 0; FrameNumber < animation->servoFrameCount; FrameNumber++)
        {
            if (FrameNumber == 0
                && animation->servos[FrameNumber]->data[i][j] >= animation->servos[FrameNumber + 1]->data[i][j])
                //^^^if it's the first frame AND current value is higher or equal to the next value, then we have a new spike
                //we put the spike's frame in "Local Maximums",and increase the number of spikes
            {
                LocalMaximums[NumberOfSpikes] = FrameNumber;
                NumberOfSpikes++;
            }
```

Comment: *dereferencing null pointer* - that would crash your program.

Comment: If you want help fixing that, you'll need to show us some of your code - enough for us to diagnose the problem, but no more.

Comment: @AdrianMole LocalMaximums[NumberOfSpikes] = FrameNumber; here is where i get my "dereferencing null pointer" warning

Comment: Then you need to check the return value of the `malloc` call. If that's `NULL` then you have to handle the error, rather than continuing and attempting to use the memory that your failed to allocate.